# AsyncStorage doesn't save data but no error

Tags: reactjs, save, native, asyncstorage

Now I am aware that there are many of questions that asked the same thing. But I also found many that implemented the right methods but nothing worked for them even peoples' answers

Basically, I wanted to use AsyncStorage to save a few user preferences. At first everything worked and was saved correctly, but then suddenly nothing worked anymore.

I kept trying and trying, and made a very interesting finding.

First here's my code:

My import:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Default State:

```
  state : AppState = {
    messages: [],
    isMuted: false
  }
```

This is my getter. It works on init:

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.getSettings();
  }

  async getSettings() {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("muted").then((muted)=> {
        if (muted != null) {
          this.setState({"isMuted": eval(muted)});
          console.log("init! "+this.state.isMuted.toString());
        } else {
          console.log("init! found null");
        }
      })

    } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  }
```

Here's my setter, it works onPress of a button

```
 onPressSpeaker = async () => {
    var muted = !this.state.isMuted;
    this.setState({"isMuted": muted});

    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("muted", this.state.isMuted.toString());
      console.log("saved! "+this.state.isMuted.toString());

      const muted = await AsyncStorage.getItem('muted');
      if(muted !== null) {
        console.log("data found! "+this.state.isMuted.toString());
      }

    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error")
    }
  };
```

I believe I set everything correctly.

But here's my log (from Flipper)

```
20:57:41.654
init! true

20:57:44.247
saved! false

20:57:44.256
data found! false

20:58:04.788
Running "Voice Message" with {"rootTag":51}

20:58:05.800
init! true
```

The last init was supposed to return the new value but it keeps returning the old value again and again, everytime I refresh (restart) the application.

Did I do something wrong? Am I missing something? Is there something I need to know about react-native-async-storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem that you are storing the **this.state.isMuted** value before the state mutates

To better understand you can try this code

```
 onPressSpeaker = async () => {
   var muted = !this.state.isMuted;
   this.setState({"isMuted": muted});
        
   try {
     //Here we are trying to log the state before Add it to Storage
     console.log('State => Before AsyncStorage.setItem', this.state.isMuted)

     await AsyncStorage.setItem("muted", this.state.isMuted.toString());

     console.log("saved! "+this.state.isMuted.toString());
        
     const muted = await AsyncStorage.getItem('muted');

       if(muted !== null) {
         console.log("data found! "+this.state.isMuted.toString());
       }
        
     } catch (e) {
              console.log("error")
       }
 };
```

Your log will now be like this

```
20:57:41.654
init! true

20:57:44.247
'State => Before AsyncStorage.setItem' true

20:57:44.247
saved! false

20:57:44.256
data found! false
```

**Solution:** So you need to write the function in the callback to the setState function

```
 storeIsMuted = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("before setItem", this.state.isMuted.toString());
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("muted", this.state.isMuted.toString());
      console.log("saved! " + this.state.isMuted.toString());
      //
      const muted = await AsyncStorage.getItem("muted");
      if (muted !== null) {
        console.log("data found! " + this.state.isMuted.toString());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
  onPressSpeaker = () => {
    var muted = !this.state.isMuted
    this.setState({ isMuted: muted }, async () => this.storeMuted());
  };
```

**Documentation**
[SetState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Much appreciated for the reply, I'm sure this is a better practice. Still this doesn't make much sense, because the item was saved as 'false', exactly what I wanted. The problem is that it did set the value but did not save on refresh. It's most likely not a code problem.

Comment: @RyotaMitarai Sorry but I don't understand, Before you store the value before it changes

Comment: Actually maybe it was this. So you're saying I 'setItem' my ''muted' to the old value (true) but while waiting, my isMuted state had updated the newest (false) which was then printed. Also, i just checked my "data found" and found it actually returns the variable not my "getItem" -_-. Alright alright. You win.

Comment: If you need help don't hesitate. Happy Coding